# Аргумент типа char* несовместим с параметром типа tchar*

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

```
DWORD gamebaseadress1 = GetModuleBaseAddress(_T(gamemmodule1), pID);
```

ошибка в `(_T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим, а что же делает этот `_T(...)`. Для этого возьмем подчищенный код с библиотеки

```
#ifdef _UNICODE 
 #define _T(c) L##c
 #define TEXT(c) L##c
#else 
 #define _T(c) c
 #define TEXT(c) c
#endif
```

То есть, грубо говоря, если определен макрос `_UNICODE`, то `_T(word)` заменяется на `Lword`. Странно, да? нет, просто в плюсах есть конструкция `L"text"`, для того, что бы подсказать компилятору, что текст в кавычках это не `const char*`,  `const wchar_t*`. Что же будет, если туда подсунуть просто какую то переменную типа `char*`? а ничего хорошего. При компиляции с отключенным `_UNICODE`, оно будет работать, а с включенным (это 99% современного кода), будет ошибка.

Как исправлять?

если тип у `gamemmodule1` `wchar_t*`, то можно просто написать

```
DWORD gamebaseadress1 = GetModuleBaseAddress(gamemmodule1, pID);
```

или даже так (как по мне, то если не нужно заморачиваться на старый код без поддержки юникода, то это самый простой вариант):

```
DWORD gamebaseadress1 = GetModuleBaseAddressW(gamemmodule1, pID);
```

Если же тип `char*`, то можно по быстрому так

```
DWORD gamebaseadress1 = GetModuleBaseAddressA(gamemmodule1, pID);
```

Но лучше имя модуля сразу получать в `wchar_t*`. или преобразовать.

А ещё лучше, хотя это и сложно, поддержать тип `TCHAR*` - это такой тип, который также зависит от `_UNICODE` и разворачивается в `char*` или `wchar_t*` или заморочится с конвертированием, но это нудно. Проще сразу в юникод стиле делать.

На почитать https://habr.com/ru/post/164193/

Comment: Если ставлю DWORD gamebaseadress1 = GetModuleBaseAddress(gamemmodule1, pID); то ошибка в gamemmodule1
Если DWORD gamebaseadress1 = GetModuleBaseAddressW(gamemmodule1, pID); то идентификатор не определен и с GetModuleBaseAddressA также

Comment: какой тип у gamemmodule1 ?

Comment: char 
CHAR gamemmodule1[] = "ACS.exe"; - вот строка кода

Comment: `char CHAR gamemodule1`? сделайте `TCHAR[] gamemodule1 = _T("ACS.exe");` и тогда будет работать `GetModuleBaseAddress(gamemmodule1, pID);` и не забыть `#include <psapi.h>`

Comment: так как, пофиксилось или никак, @gyd1ni ?

Comment: Да всё окей спасибо огромное!

Comment: @gyd1ni,  тут принято ставить галочку, что бы показать другим, что этот ответ решает поставленный вопрос